# add JButton into frame with JTable

Tags: java, jtable, jframe, jbutton

I would like to know how to put a button inside a frame that contain JTable inside. (The button should not be inside a cell, but after the table ends)
Here is the example code I wrote so far:

> > class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame
> >
> > {
> >
> > > > // Instance attributes used in this example
> > > >
> > > > private JPanel      topPanel;
> > > >
> > > > private JTable      table;
> > > >
> > > > private JScrollPane scrollPane;
> > > >            private JButton     update_Button;

```
// Constructor of main frame
public SimpleTableExample()
{
    // Set the frame characteristics
    setTitle("Add new item" );
    setSize(300, 200);
    setBackground( Color.gray );

    // Create a panel to hold all other components
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );



    // Create columns names
    String columnNames[] = {"Item Description", "Item Type", "Item Price"};

    // Create some data
    String dataValues[][] = {{ "0", "Entree", "0" }};

    // Create a new table instance
    table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );

    ////////////////////////////

    JComboBox item_Type_Combobox = new JComboBox();
    item_Type_Combobox = new JComboBox(item_Type.values());
    TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    column.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(item_Type_Combobox));


    ////////////////////////////    



    // Add the table to a scrolling pane
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

}
```

}

How do I add button after the table I created?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to add another component below (for example) the table you could use:

```
topPanel.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Is that what you mean?